# How to copy an input element with its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple textboxes generated by AJAX.

```
<input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1_nm'  />
```

What I'd like to do, when I press a button. The input is all copied inside a different div with its new value inserted by user.

I use

```
$('#txt1').html();
```

but, the value is not copied only the textbox

Comment: Use $('#txt1').value();

Comment: try $('#txt1').clone()

Comment: a good approach should be to create an element and append it to the document and then assign the value as using `html()` will create a duplicate id for the elements

Comment: Try .clone() https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of `clone()` so that you get the element with its value. Type anything in the textbox in the snippet below and press the `Copy` button.

```js
//detect the click of the copy button
$('#copyBtn').click(function(){
  //get the clonned element
  var inputElement = $('#txt1').clone();
  //add clonned element to a new div
  $('#copiedDiv').html(inputElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1_nm'  />
</div>
<div id='copiedDiv'></div>
<button id='copyBtn'>Copy</button>
```

If you want to add multiple cloned items then you will require to change the `id` of the `input` element and then append that to the page. You can do like this to achieve it,

```js
//detect the click of the copy button
$('#copyBtn').click(function(){
  //get the last input item
  var $inputEl = $('input[name="txt1_nm"]:last');
  //get the next id number
  var num = parseInt( $inputEl.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
  //clone and set a new id for this element
  var $cloneEl = $inputEl.clone().prop('id', 'txt'+num );
  //add clonned element to a new div
  $('#copiedDiv').append($cloneEl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1_nm'  />
</div>
<div id='copiedDiv'></div>
<button id='copyBtn'>Copy</button>
```

Comment: This will only run once, because it will create duplicate ids.

Comment: I have added a new snippet for that. Which handles this @Akar

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

`$('#txt1').clone()`

It will perform a deep clone of that element with all of its content.

**NOTE**: Cloning an element will also duplicate its ID if it has one.
You should change any `ids` to `classes` beforehand.

This is from the documentation:

> Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Comment: it prints `[object Object]` when appended

Comment: Did you use: `$('#txt1').clone().appendTo('.container');`?

Comment: I use this `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').clone()`

Comment: Try using: `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').clone().html()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click','#myBtn',function(){
value=$('#txt1').val();

$('#myDiv').empty();
$('#myDiv').append($('#txt1').clone());
$('#txt1').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' id='txt1' name='txt1_nm'  />
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Click Me</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```